# i have been trying to deploy mocks for my hardhat-raffle , but i encountered this problem

Tags: solidity, contract-development, blockchain, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

```js
const { network, ethers } = require("hardhat")
const {developmentChains} =require('../helper-hardhat-config')

const BASE_FEE=ethers.utils.parseEther("0.25") // 0.25 is the premium amount to be used
//it cost 0.25 LINK per request for the mocks [check premium this is measure in gasLink ]
const GAS_PRICE_LINK=1e9 //link per gas used for the mocks deployment




module.exports=async ({deployments,getNamedAccounts})=>{
 const {deploy,log}=deployments
 const {deployer}=await getNamedAccounts()
 const chainId=network.config.chainId
 const args=[BASE_FEE,GAS_PRICE_LINK]

 if(developmentChains.includes(network.name)){
         log('local network detected! deploying mocks......')
         await deploy('VRFCoordinatorV2Mock',{
           from:deployer,
           log:true,
           args:args,
         })
         log('mocks deployed.....')
         log('--------------------------------')
 }
}

module.exports.tags=['all','mocks']
```

i have this encountered this error:

Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="0.01", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.6.2)

please i need help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Specify the base fee like this:

```js
const BASE_FEE = "250000000000000000";
```